# generate barcode on android google sheets

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-sheets, barcode

I have a Google Sheet that we use to generate picking tickets for our warehouse.  There are several columns that have barcodes.  They are generated using the following function call:

=image("http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=" & E3 & "&style=68&type=C128B&width=200&height=80&xres=1&font=0", 3)

This works perfectly and does exactly what we need it to do, which is using a PC to print the ticket and hand it off to the warehouse guys.

In my attempt to make the process more streamlined I want to replace the tickets with an Android tablet and let them scan from there.  The benefit to that is that they can also manually update the Sheet with exceptions and other items that are not bar coded.  Here is what I have run into:

1. On the android if I view the Sheet through the Chrome browser it I can see the bar codes fine, but as soon as I hit the edit button, it opens the sheet in the Sheets app and I can no longer see the bar codes.
2. If I open the sheet in the Sheets app I can edit the cells but can't see the bar codes.
   Note, when using my PC workstation I can see the bar codes and edit the sheet with no problems.

So, not sure if this is actually a programming question or not, but what can I do in order to be able to view the bar codes in the Sheets app or to be able to edit the sheet in the browser like I do on my PC?  Yes, I have requested the desktop site in options for Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated, I would really like to roll this out and save some paper.

Answer (score 0):

I am now answering my own question in case anyone runs into this.  You need to request the desktop site (in Chrome options) as soon as you log into Google Drive **AND** after you open the sheet.  Now the sheet will switch from view only mode to edit mode in the browser.

Bonus question: Is there anyway you can force the browser to always open stuff in the desktop site?  Specifically for Google stuff, but for any other site really since larger tablets can handle the 'full' site and don't need to be redirected to the m.version of the site.